# F# SQL typeprovider

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

According to the Microsoft [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#BKMK_SetUpTypeProv) I should be able to instantiate a db schema like this:

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=MYSERVER\INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
```

In Visual Studio 2011, F# 3.0 and .Net 4.5 this gives me an error and I have to use:

```
[<Generate>] type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=MYSERVER\INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
```

which does work.

I don't understand why (I'm new to F#) and would like to know if there is something wrong with my setup, if this is just a beta thing or if this is a bug?

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I reinstalled Visual Studio 11 beta the error went away.

Comment: Please consider marking your answer as accepted so that the question did not appear in the list of unanswered.